# Copy paste generator

Tags: fonts, copy, generator, paste

How can I make copy paste generator like f.e. lingojam, from which
I will can copy and paste text with all formatting  .

I ask about this problem because I want to do it with another font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with another font because it's not really formatting, it's rather replacing regular characters with other Unicode characters that look like the same letter in a different design.

For example, the  is the character [`MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL L`](https://charbase.com/1d4f5-unicode-mathematical-bold-script-small-l) with code point U+1D4F5.

It is basically abusing the characters that exist in Unicode for a different purpose.

If the character "designs" that you are looking for exist in Unicode already, you can build such a tool very simply, just write code that replaces all occurences of the character `l` (U+006C) by the character  (U+1D4F5) for example (for all the letters of course). If no such characters exist already, then you are out of luck.